# Items get deleted from ListView but not from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite, custom-adapter

I have seen similar question but mine is bit different.
I have CustomListAdapter with delete button

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQMJ6.png)

Issue is once I click this delete button Item gets deleted from ListView but not from SQLite databases. Every time I refreshes the activity all data comes back.

DBHandler

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 6;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "usersdb";
    private static final String TABLE_Users = "plate_details";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";


    public DBHandler(Context context){
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_Users + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT" + ");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        // Drop older table if exist
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Users);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // **** CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations ***** //


    // Adding new User Details
    void insertUserDetails(String name){
        //Get the Data Repository in write mode
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
        ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
        cValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_Users,null, cValues);
        db.close();
    }


    // Get User Details
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetUsers(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT name  FROM "+ TABLE_Users;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("name",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));

            userList.add(user);
        }
        return  userList;
    }
    // Get User Details based on userid
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetUserByUserId(int userid){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT name FROM "+ TABLE_Users;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Users, new String[]{KEY_NAME}, KEY_ID+ "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(userid)},null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToNext()){
            HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("name",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
            userList.add(user);
        }
        return  userList;
    }

    // Delete All Details

    public void DeleteAll(String tablename) {

        String selectQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_Users;

        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL(selectQuery);
    }

    public long getID (int position) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return Long.parseLong(KEY_ID);
    }


    // Delete User Details
    public void DeleteUser(int userid){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_Users, KEY_ID+" = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(userid)});
        db.close();
    }

    // Update User Details
    public int UpdateUserDetails(String location, String designation, int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cVals = new ContentValues();
        int count = db.update(TABLE_Users, cVals, KEY_ID+" = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        return  count;
    }
}
```

CustomListAdapter

```
class CustomListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

    private Cursor mCursor;
    private int mRowIdColumn;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static final String TAG = "";
    customButtonListener customListner;

    public interface customButtonListener {
        public void onButtonClickListner(int position,String value);
    }

    public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {
        this.customListner = listener;
    }

    private Context context;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    public CustomListAdaptor(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {

        super(context, R.layout.list_row, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;

    }


    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        DBHandler dba = new DBHandler(this.context);

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.id = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.id);
            viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_lst_item_del);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        final HashMap<String, String> temp = data.get(position);


        String name = temp.get("name");
        String id = temp.get("id");

        viewHolder.text.setText(name);
        viewHolder.id.setText(id);

        viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (customListner != null) {

                    Log.d(TAG,"id:" + getItemId(position));
                    Log.d(TAG,"item:" + getItem(position));
                    Log.d(TAG,"position:" + position);

                    dba.DeleteUser(position);
                    data.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public TextView id;
        Button button;
    }
}
```

DetailsActivity.java

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements customButtonListener {
    Intent intent;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);
        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);

        DBHandler qu =  new DBHandler(this); // Dbhelper class object

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = db.GetUsers();



        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.user_list);

        CustomListAdaptor adapter = new CustomListAdaptor(DetailsActivity.this, userList);
        adapter.setCustomButtonListner(DetailsActivity.this);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        Button back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        Button clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                qu.DeleteAll("TABLE_Users");

                startActivity(getIntent());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cleared",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onButtonClickListner(int position, String value) {
        Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, "Button click " + value,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: `dba.DeleteUser(position);` That should be `dba.DeleteUser(dba.getID((position));` i think.

Comment: `public void DeleteUser(int userid)` If you call a void function then you dont know if it does what you want it to do. Make it `public boolean DeleteUser(int userid)` and use the result of `db.delete()`.

Comment: when i start from fresh with no records in database. the id of records in sqlite database are like 1,2,3,.... and the id of items in listview are 0,1,2,... So when i use this DeleteUser function it does delete those matching ids 1 and 2... when after too many records added and deleted... the listview id no more matches with actual database id so yes DeleteUser function is working..

Comment: The issue is how would i get the real database id when i click that delete button?? Because once i delete items get deleted from listview but after refreshing the activity all records comes back which clearly means that they are not deleted from database..  So please help me how can i pass the real database id to this DeleteUser function when i click the delete button.

Comment: You have already `dba.getID((position)` so that should not be the problem. If the whole list comes back then no item was deleted. So first learn to delete items. Dont use a listview for that. You did not react on suggestion to change void for boolean.